# Why can't I see section B when it appears to be just like sections A and C?

Tags: cognito-forms

I'm adding sections (not repeating) to my form. I have 3 sections: A, B, C
The section name for A and C show up when I click on a field within that section and create a condition for when it will be shown. Section B, however, doesn't show up.
Example: form.A.MakeASelection, form.C.MakeASelection
But form.B.MakeASelection is missing.
I have deleted and recreated section B. I have clicked on Save about 100 times. I have closed and reopened the Cognito website.
What am I don't wrong? Why can't I see section B when it appears to be just like sections A and C?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I figured it out. You can't see the form title if you are currently working within that form. If I click on a different section then section B form title shows up. Makes sense.
Thanks for being a great listener. ;O